# Is there any way to perform an action before a web worker closes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, web-worker

I'm writing an event logger using web workers to handle it in a secondary process. The worker collects events locally, then sends them out as a batch every few seconds.

I need a way to send any unsent batches if the browser or tab closes. Is there any way for a web worker to listen for something like an `onclose` event?

I realize I can do this in the application itself, but the logger is a node package that is going to be used in multiple places, and I'd rather not make the front end responsible for cleaning up the event logger.

Comment: I've been through those crazyness of quality guys wanting reporting all the time, even if windows blue screens. Tell them it's impossible, they won't argue :)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/onclose

Comment: @dlkulp oh, man, I hope so. Let me try it.

Comment: @dlkulp It doesn't seem to. I could be missing something, though. Will keep at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing mentioned in the [processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/#the-worker-s-lifetime) section of the web worker spec, in particular the "Kill a Worker" and "Terminate a Worker" sections. I don't think you have much choice but to have code on the UI thread send a message to the worker to tell it to clean up.

Comment: That's the conclusion I was coming to, as well, but I was hoping there was something I'd missed. I'll leave this open for a while, but barring a miracle, I'll likely end up marking this as the resolution.

Comment: @JesseF: Yeah, I'd give it a full day at least. Would be glad to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do `self.onclose = function() { ... };` which will be called when the worker is closed.  More can be read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/onclose).  Since workers have their own context, you have to access the scope via the `WorkerGlobalScope`.  The exposed `WorkerGlobalScope.self` should allow you to access events such as `onclose()`.

The caveat here appears to be that the API is not standardized.  You'll have to check your browser to see if it's supported (and it looks like Microsoft hasn't implemented this so good luck with IE/Edge).  The best way to do this cross-platform for now is probably what @T.J. Crowder suggested having code on the UI to ask the worker to close.

Comment: I'm trying that right now, haven't gotten it to work yet. Testing in Chrome (supposedly it's supported), going to try it in FF as well.

Comment: Update: Doesn't seem to work in Firefox, either. Not going to bother with IE/Edge.

Comment: Update 2: After further research, it looks like the close() method is still experimental, and it's compatibility is questionable. Looks like I'll have to revisit this later on, once it's fully baked.